# In real laser applications, how big is the complex parameter (i.e. <n>) of the corresponding coherent state of the field?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, quantum-optics

In quantum optics, the output from a laser is modelled using a coherent state; what are some orders-of-magnitude for the complex parameter (usually denoted $\alpha$) of the coherent state corresponding to real laser fields used in experiments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quantum of EM radiation has energy $E=hc/\lambda$.  For a number state, the energy is $E=nhc/\lambda$.  To find the power this corresponds to, imagine that all of those excitations are being generated in a laser in a time $\tau$.  The rate of energy production (the power) is then $P=nhc/\lambda\tau$.

The average occupation number of a coherent state is $\left< n\right> = |\alpha|^2$.  This gives us $$P=\frac{|\alpha|^2hc}{\lambda\tau}$$

Now take as an example a laser pointer operating at 534 nm, having a power of 1 mW. Take $\tau$ = 1 s in order to get a proper S.I. unit (joules per *second*).

If I set my calculator on that I get $\alpha\approx 5\times10^7$.  (Check my work on that.)

Comment: Thanks! I don't see why one can choose the time to be 1s. Your argument up to that point suggests that $|\alpha|^{2}$ should grow in time. This makes sense if we talk about pumping light into a cavity with no loss, but I don't know how to interpret that for a free-propagating laser beam.

Comment: Actually, I think I've found of a way to rationalise it. The Glauber expression for the current from a photodetector ($\langle \hat{E}^{(-)}\hat{E}^{(+)} \rangle$) says a coherent beam gives in a constant signal $|\alpha|^{2}$. But the Glauber photocurrent is an instantaneous quantity, so that actual number of photons you receive would be proportional to  $|\alpha|^{2} \tau$. When choosing a $\tau$ in your equation, we're also choosing the time over which the beam is measured by a detector, and so choosing 1s is convenient because $|\alpha|^{2}$ implicitly becomes a rate in seconds.